# How to make the header of a table from 2 line to 4 line?

Tags: tables, multirow

I had tried to increase the number from `2` to `4` where I need 4 lines

```
\multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\ (Class 11 sample sample \& \\ Class 22 sample sample \\ Reference X sample sample)}} &
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
     \multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\ (Class 11 sample sample \& \\ Class 22 sample sample \\ Reference X sample sample)}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}}\\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    &{\textbf{Accuracy}}
     & {\textbf{Inaccuracy}} \\
     \midrule
    Pair 11 (A8 \& B35) & 0  &   0 \\
    Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0   &  0 \\
    Pair 13 (A8 \& B32) & 0   &  0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify: Are the column headers just dummy text? If so, could you please prepare something that is closer to the actual text that is supposed to be in the column headers?

Comment: I have also again edited the tags since this question is again not related to `tabularx` but to `multirow`.

Comment: @leandriis. thanks. i will take note this, and posted another question with your advices.

Comment: I have seen your follow up question but I unfortunately can't see an information regarding my questions in my [previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523657/how-to-make-the-header-of-a-table-from-2-line-to-4-line#comment1324781_523657). Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. The column headers is not dummy text. It is exactly what I want, 4 row in first box (`{Pair number \\ (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                        Class 22 sample sample \\
                        Reference X sample sample)}` and then only 2 row in second box `Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)` and `Accuracy Inaccuracy`

Comment: Could you please explain what "Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)"  means? Also why is the word "sample"  repeated 6 times in "{Pair number \\ (Class 11 sample sample \& \\ Class 22 sample sample \\ Reference X sample sample)}"? Couldn't you shorten this significantly?

Comment: @leandriis, It is not dummy text, but is a word. So "Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)"  is "Measurement of Accuracy" and {Pair number \\ (Class 11 tolerance sample \& \\ Class 22 tolerance sample \\ Reference X tolerance sample)}". I can edit the follow up questions, is needed

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Just for my understanding: "Pair number" refers to "Pair 11", "Class 11 tolerance sample"  refers to "A8"  and "Class 22 tolerance sample"  refers to "B35". But where can we find an entry that refers to "Reference X tolerance sample" in the table?

Comment: @leandriis, My mistake in the table. Initially is only "Class 11 and Class 22" which work fine for my table, then I added in "Reference X tolerance sample" and it make the table larger.  So it supose to be "Pair 11 (A8  & B35 & X22)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Number of text lines in `\multirow` cells had to be smaller or equal to number of text lines in spanned table rows. This is not the case in your table: `\multirow` contain four lines of text, spanned table rows only two lines. To solve this discrepancy you have more possibilities:

- added fake (empty) text lines so that spanned cells will have (at least) four lines
- make table rows taller by adding appropriate height of strut on end of cells' texts
- rephrase text in `\multirow` cell so, that it will have only two line of text

I would go with the last possibility. Since the context of table is unknown, I can give you only general advice: move description the intention of the table or wide description of contents of data collected in a some column out of table body. For example to the table caption or table legend or describe it in the document text (this we cant do instead of you).

Off-topic remarks:

- This question is at least the third your question with similar topic. So far I didn't notice, that you would in the follows-up question consider solutions proposed in the received answers and comments. Why?
- In preamble you load some package twice. This usually not harm document, but can cause clash between packages and (of course) overwrite eventual settings/options of loaded packages. For your own good remove all duplicate loading. Also for MWE load only to your problem relevant packages.

**Addendum:** An example of table, which consider the first option how to solve you problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    &       &           \\  % fake line
    \addlinespace
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
 \multirow{-4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
                        (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                        Class 22 sample sample \\
                        Reference X sample sample)}}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
     \midrule
Pair 11 (A8  \& B35) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 13 (A8  \& B32) & 0    &   0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would we able to make the `Accuracy` content move to middle, like in line 2, and 3. Currently is in line `3,4`.

Comment: @ann, you ca do this yourself. Investigate provided solution and try to make change yourself. Apparently you miss the point of my answer. Showed example is just to demonstrate how ugly you can write table.

Comment: The only i made changes is change to `\begin{tabular}{lcc}` which is the simpliest I can understand. I tried `delete the fake line`, and change from `-4` to `-5`. Not quite working