# Question using Multirow and Multicolumn together

Tags: tables, multirow

This is a question link from a previous question [How to make the header of a table from 2 line to 4 line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523657/how-to-make-the-header-of-a-table-from-2-line-to-4-line?noredirect=1#comment1324782_523657)

The proposed answer is using:

```
\multirow{-4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
```

I could not understand the meaning of `-4`. usually is `positive number`.

[image: w]

Basically, I want to have the content to be a center, so the table looks nicer

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    &       &           \\  % fake line
    \addlinespace
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
 \multirow{-4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
                        (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                        Class 22 sample sample \\
                        Reference X sample sample)}}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
     \midrule
Pair 11 (A8  \& B35) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 13 (A8  \& B32) & 0    &   0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Below is the solution I tried to move around.

(1) If I delete our the `& & \\ %fake line`, and add in several `\addlinespace`

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
     &       &           \\  % fake line
     \addlinespace
      \addlinespace
       \addlinespace
             \addlinespace
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
 \multirow{-4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
                        (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                        Class 22 sample sample \\
                        Reference X sample sample)}}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
     &  &    \\  % fake line
     \midrule
```

[image]

(2) I tried to add in `& & \\ %fake line` at the bottom. But looks ugly.

```
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    % &       &           \\  % fake line
     \addlinespace
      \addlinespace
       \addlinespace
             \addlinespace
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
 \multirow{-4}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
                        (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                        Class 22 sample sample \\
                        Reference X sample sample)}}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
    % &  &    \\  % fake line
     \midrule
```

[image]

(3) I am taking of using 
`\multirow` and `\multicolumn` together.

```
&   \mutlirow{0}{*}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}}\\
```

But couldn't make it up.

Answer (score 1):

A solution playing with `\addlinespace` and `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf},
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering\renewcommand{\theadset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}}
     \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \toprule
    \addlinespace[0.8ex]
       \multirowthead{2}{Pair number \\
                            (Class 11 sample sample \& \\
                            Class 22 sample sample \\
                            Reference X sample sample)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Accuracy Accu Accuracy (\%)}}\\
    \addlinespace[0.6ex]
        \cmidrule{2-3}
    \addlinespace[0.3ex]
        & \thead[r]{Accuracy} & \thead[r]{Inaccuracy} \\
    \addlinespace[1ex]
         \midrule
    Pair 11 (A8 \& B35) & 0 & 0 \\
    Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0 & 0 \\
    Pair 13 (A8 \& B32) & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the additional information provided in the comments to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523657/134144), here are three possible layouts. Personally, I'd prefer the last one.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    \multirow{4.5}{*}{\thead{Pair number \\
                        (Class 11 tolerance sample \& \\
                        Class 22 tolerance sample \\
                        Reference X tolerance sample)}}        &           \\  % fake line
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Measurement of Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
    \\
     \midrule
Pair 11 (A8  \& B35 \& X22) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 13 (A8  \& B32) & 0    &   0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    \addlinespace
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Measurement of\\ Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3}
 \multirow{-3}{*}{\thead{Pair number 
                        (Class 11 tolerance \\sample \& 
                        Class 22 tolerance sample \\
                        Reference X tolerance sample)}}
    & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Inaccuracy}                   \\
     \midrule
Pair 11 (A8  \& B35 \& X22) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 13 (A8  \& B32) & 0    &   0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
\thead{Pair number} & \thead{Accuracy (\%)} & \thead{Inaccuracy (\%)}                   \\
     \midrule
Pair 11 (A8  \& B35 \& X22) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 12 (A10 \& B42) & 0    &   0 \\
Pair 13 (A8  \& B32) & 0    &   0 \\
        \midrule
     \multicolumn{3}{p{10cm}}{\footnotesize A.. = Class 11 tolerance sample, B.. = Class 22 tolerance sample, X.. = Reference X tolerance sample}\\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I also think of adding as footnote. thanks a lot