# Content does not centre in a table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

This is a follow-up question from [using multirow and multi column together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523694/question-using-multirow-and-multicolumn-together)

Basically, i want a table look professional and centre.

In Example 1 below: there is a word outside the table
using `\begin{tabular}{lccc}`.

Example 2: The content is not center.
using `\begin{tabular}{lSSS}`

[image]

I have no idea what else i can change to make the table looks better.

My Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lccc}
     \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Pair Number\tnote{a}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{System Nuclear Accuracy(\%)}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}}      & {\textbf{BB}}      & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule     
    Pair 1 (A45 \& A33) & 22.22 & 22.22 & 33.33\\
    Pair 2 (A33 \& A33) & 33.33 & 33.11 & 33.11\\
    Pair 3 (A33 \& A22) & 33.3 & 19.33 & 33.89\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Pair Number\tnote{a}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{System Nuclear Accuracy(\%)}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}}      & {\textbf{BB}}      & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule     
    Pair 1 (A45 \& A33) & 22.22 & 22.22 & 33.33\\
    Pair 2 (A33 \& A33) & 33.33 & 33.11 & 33.11\\
    Pair 3 (A33 \& A22) & 33.3 & 19.33 & 33.89\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}    



\end{document}
```

Comment: `table-format` should be `2.2` instead of `3.0`. (As an example, `1.2` would correpond to numbers with 1 place before the comma and 2 decimal places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the `table-format` from `3.0` to `2.2` will solve the horizontal alignment issue in the second table. (Personally, I'd reduce `table-column-width` to `1.5cm` in order to decrease the amount of white space in the table.

The text in the first table overflows since the text in the multicolumn is wider than the width of the three columns combined. To overcome this, you can either increase the column widths as you did in the second example or add a linebreak.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Pair Number\tnote{a}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{System Nuclear\\ Accuracy(\%)}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}}      & {\textbf{BB}}      & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule     
    Pair 1 (A45 \& A33) & 22.22 & 22.22 & 33.33\\
    Pair 2 (A33 \& A33) & 33.33 & 33.11 & 33.11\\
    Pair 3 (A33 \& A22) & 33.3 & 19.33 & 33.89\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Pair Number\tnote{a}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{System Nuclear Accuracy(\%)}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
    &{\textbf{AA}}      & {\textbf{BB}}      & {\textbf{CC}}\\
     \midrule     
    Pair 1 (A45 \& A33) & 22.22 & 22.22 & 33.33\\
    Pair 2 (A33 \& A33) & 33.33 & 33.11 & 33.11\\
    Pair 3 (A33 \& A22) & 33.3 & 19.33 & 33.89\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}    



\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Just one small question. What does `S` means in `\begin{tabular}{lSSS}` in simple English?

Comment: @aan: There are different "column specifiers". Some of the standard ones are `c` and `l`. Where `c` stands for: 1 horizontally centered column. `S` is also a column specifier. `lSSS` therefore translates to: 1 left ligned column, 3 S-columns. `S` is defined by the `siunitx` package and with the help of this column type, you can align numbers with respect to the decimal marker. For example compare the alignment of numbers in your first and second example. Especially look at the "33.3"  value and you will spot the difference.