# table-format=2.2 for 2 decimal place, what happened if have integer and % in data?

Tags: tables, siunitx, multicolumn

This is following up question [Content is not center in tabl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524004/content-does-not-centre-in-a-table)

I able to take into account using `table-format=2.2` for data example `22.22`. 
What happened if I have an integer for example `10` and alsp percentage `22.22%` in the table.

Is there any way to make it center and look good?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{System Nuclear Accuracy}}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
& {\textbf{AA}}
& {\textbf{BB}}
& {\textbf{CC}} \\
\midrule
N       & {10}  &  {10}  & {10}     \\
    Mean    & 33.83\%  & 33.67\%  & 33.78\%  \\
    Median  & 44.33\%  & 33.89\%  & 44.83\%  \\
    Variance & 254.42 & 444.708 & 33.79 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why not remove the % sign next to the numbers and use "Mean (%)" instead?

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I did consider that before. But the `10` will be alight in decimal places. If i put `10.00` , it seemed weird that N have decimal place.

Comment: Remove the set of {} around the 10.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks! I have so many questions. It works. `\begin{tabular}{
  lSS[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]`. thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest one of the three following tables.

In the first one, I have corrected the `table-format` from `2.2` to `3.3`. This is necessary, since your longest number is "444.708"  that has 3 integer and 3 decimal places. Threfore `3.3`. I have also removed the set of `{}` around the `10` since you indicated in a comment that you also wanted to align the 10 with the other numbers. (Personally, I'd keep the 10 centered.) As you can see, there will now be a horizontal white space between the numbers and the percent sign. You can either get rid of that by rounding all numbers to the same number of decimal places (as Zarko shows [in their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524019/134144))  or you can add `table-align-text-post=false` as I did in the second example.

In the third table, I have removed the percent signs and added them in the first column. 
Instead of 6 percent signs, you will only have two of them with this method.

In all table, I have also commented out `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}` to remove the additional white space between teh columns. I have also added two simplifications to save some typing time and make the code shorter. Instead of retyping the `S` columns with all their options, you can use `*{<number>}{<column specification>}` to repeat the same column. I have used this in table one and two. Instead of having to add the options directly to the column specifier, as in `S[<options here>]`, you can also make use of `\sisetup{table-format=3.3}`. I have used this in the third table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=3.3,table-space-text-post = \si{\percent}]}
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{System Nuclear Accuracy}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
& {\thead{AA}}
& {\thead{BB}}
& {\thead{CC}} \\
\midrule
N        & 10       &  10      & 10       \\
Mean     & 33.83\%  & 33.67\%  & 33.78\%  \\
Median   & 44.33\%  & 33.89\%  & 44.83\%  \\
Variance & 254.42   & 444.708  & 33.79    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=3.3,table-space-text-post = \si{\percent}, table-align-text-post=false]}
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{System Nuclear Accuracy}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
& {\thead{AA}}
& {\thead{BB}}
& {\thead{CC}} \\
\midrule
N        & 10       &  10      & 10       \\
Mean     & 33.83\%  & 33.67\%  & 33.78\%  \\
Median   & 44.33\%  & 33.89\%  & 44.83\%  \\
Variance & 254.42   & 444.708  & 33.79    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.3}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{3}{S}
}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{System Nuclear Accuracy}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-4}
& {\thead{AA}}
& {\thead{BB}}
& {\thead{CC}} \\
\midrule
N        & 10       &  10      & 10       \\
Mean (\si{\percent})    & 33.83  & 33.67  & 33.78  \\
Median (\si{\percent})   & 44.33  & 33.89  & 44.83  \\
Variance & 254.42   & 444.708  & 33.79    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf},
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]               % <---
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.2,          % <---
         table-space-text-post=\%,
         round-mode=places,         % <---
         round-precision=2          % <---              
         }
\begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S}}          % <---
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{System Nuclear Accuracy}}\\  % <---
     \cmidrule{2-4}
        & {\thead{AA}}  & {\thead{BB}}  & {\thead{CC}}  \\  % <---
    \midrule
N           & {10}      &  {10}     & {10}              \\
Mean        & 33.83\,\% & 33.67\,\% & 33.78\,\%         \\  % <---
Median      & 44.33\,\% & 33.89\,\% & 44.83\,\%         \\  % <---
Variance    & 254.42    & 444.708   & 33.79             \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why 4 S type columns?

Comment: @leandriis, oh, this was error. Now is corrected.